# Sort ActiveX Combobox list data

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have an ActiveX combo box that sources its data from a list of suburbs, which occur in my spreadsheet in alphabetical order. The suburbs have a rank assigned to them, however it is important that the order in which they appear from my combo box is based on rank. They need to remain in the spreadsheet in alphabetical order though.

Is there a way of doing this in Excel, with or without VBA?

Comment: I think of two ways. You are correct, one is `VBA` and another is using a `Helper Range` where you have another list based on rank. You can write a formula which arrange the list based on rank.

Comment: Thanks L42. Do you mean taking my current list, sorting it based on rank (elsewhere) and then referencing the combo box to that list instead?

Comment: Cool. That's correct. Or you can try what Jean posted :)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to sort by rank, populate the box, then re-sort alphabetically to revert to the original state.

```
Set r = Sheet1.Range("C4:D7") ' or wherever your data is located
r.Sort r.Columns(2), xlAscending ' sort by rank
Sheet1.ComboBox1.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(r.Columns(1))
r.Sort r.Columns(1), xlAscending ' sort by suburb name
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I think I may go with having a "hidden" helper list elsewhere that sorts on rank.